# Custom JButton subclass setIcon method not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource, imageicon

*EDIT: This is a Netbeans project.*
So I have created a subclass of JButton called Card. I am trying to set an icon to the button on creation.

```
package matchinggame;

public class Card extends JButton {

    final static ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");

    ...

    public Card(int secretIconIndex) { 
        //Set the button's icon to the default icon
        setIcon(defaultIcon);
        ... 
    }

    ...

}
```

If you were wondering, the location of the "cardback.jpg" image is:

```
C:\Users\Jesse\SkyDrive\Documents\RCS\Grade 12\ICS4U\M9\MatchingGame\src\matchinggame\cardback.jpg
```

It is in the same folder/package as all the classes, so I believe I can leave the relative filepath like that. When I run the program, all the buttons are just blank (no text or icon). Is this a constructor issue or filepath issue?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths?

Comment: Yep, wrong paths are where I'd look. Have you used a debugger or println statements or a logger to check program state at this point, to see if the icon is null for instance?

Comment: Never used absolute paths before, but I just tried the absolute path and the image shows up now! But now this will not work on anyone else's computer... Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Problem is in filepath. As I understood you have created package named `matchinggame` in your project and added icons in that package. If so, you should set your icon like this: setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/matchinggame/cardback.jpg")));

Comment: Use resources, not files, since you'll likely want to jar this at some point.

Comment: Thank you all! I placed all my images in a "resources" package, and created ImageIcon 's as such:
`final ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/cardback.jpg"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered in the question comments. brano88 and Hovercraft Full of Eels said to use resources instead of file paths. The following fixed my problem:

```
final ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/cardback.jpg"));
```

I put this in my Card class.

**Note:** I moved my images to a new "resources" package inside the "src" folder in Eclipse or "Source Packages" folder in Netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

If this is an Eclipse project store the image in a `resources/` folder in the `src/` folder.

```
setButtonIcon("cardback.jpg");

public void setButtonIcon(String filename) {
  ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/"+filename);
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(input));
  super.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Comment: I like the use of `ImageIO` but you could simple use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/matchinggame/cardback.jpg");` and get the same result ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using the "eclipse" the image must be inside the folder "src" to use an absolute path.
Use: 
`new File("cardback.jpg").exists() // to see if the file is in the right place`